# How to draw a Line between two ImageViews by getting the positions of the ImageViews?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is MainActivity.java code which gets the positions of the imagViews and tries to generate a lineView between the ImageViews by getting the coordinates of the ImageViews.

I'm getting the coordinates of the ImageViews but it's not showing the line between them.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView one,two;
    private LineView lineView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lineView=findViewById(R.id.lineView);

        one=findViewById(R.id.one);
        two=findViewById(R.id.two);  
        Random random = new Random();
        int x=random.nextInt(500);
        int y=random.nextInt(500);
        one.setX(x);
        one.setY(y);
        int c=x;
        int d=y;
        PointF pointA=new PointF(c,d);
        x=random.nextInt(500);
        y=random.nextInt(500);
        two.setX(x);
        two.setY(y);
        c=x;
        d=y;
        PointF pointB=new PointF(c,d);
        lineView.setPointA(pointA);
        lineView.setPointB(pointB);
        lineView.draw();
    }
}
```

This is activity_main.xml that contains the ImageViews and LineView.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
<xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="116dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="197dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/one" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="133dp"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/two" />

    <com.example.testing.LineView
        android:id="@+id/lineView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the Lineview.java code that generates the line view widget and its operations .

```java
public class LineView extends View {

    PointF pointA,pointB;
    private Paint paint =new Paint();
    public LineView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public LineView(Context context,  AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


        super.onDraw(canvas);

        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        canvas.drawLine(pointA.x,pointA.y,pointB.x,pointB.y,paint);
    }

    public void setPointA(PointF point)
    {
        pointA=point;
    }
    public void setPointB(PointF point)
    {
        pointB=point;
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add your code [as an edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54809887/edit) **as text**. Please also take a moment to read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Pl add code directly instead of posting code screenshots. Also there is no code for xml and mainactivity.

Comment: Please note the emphasis on the words **"as text"** (i.e. copy and paste). Screenshots of code can be difficult for others to read and understand, please help us to help you.

Comment: I have changed the question.Please go through it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your view - put this `View` between your images:

```
 <View
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

Comment: I want to add the line by getting the position of the ImageViews

Comment: I changed the question.Please go through the quetion again.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical line between two image views in android

```
<View
  android:layout_width="1dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#FF0000FF"/>
```

Comment: I changed the question.Pleae go through the question again.

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal line between two image views in android

```
<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:background="#FF0000FF"/>
```